# Container hostname from the docker host in compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In a standalone docker installation I need to set in compose the container hostname in a form like `${DOCKER_HOST_HOSTNAME}-${A_RANDOM_STRING}`

I tried with

```
service:
  myservice:
    hostname: "{{.Node.Hostname}}-{{.Task.ID}}"
  ...
```

but it seems to work only with Swarm, because the value is passed litterally.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: You can use an ```.env``` file and pass it to the ```docker-compose``` command

Answer (score 0):

I managed this using

```
service:
  myservice:
    hostname: ${HOSTNAME}-${RANDOMID}
  ...
```

and running the compose like this

`HOSTNAME=$(hostname -f) RANDOMID=$RANDOM docker compose up`